# Maintenance holding page while migrating website

Tags: database, import, migration, localhost, maintenance

I was hoping someone might be able to help me with the right procedure for establishing a holding page while migrating a local WP site to an already live server.

I know there are lots of maintenance mode plugins. However, if I'm migrating/replacing WordPress files on the server and migrating the database, won't the plugin cease to function during this time?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Create a index.html file at root folder and redirect all request to that file with 302 or 307 status code can do the job.

Answer (score 3):

Simplest method to put your website in Maintenance mode, is to create a `.maintenance` file in your WordPress root folder with following content.

```
<?php $upgrading = time(); ?>
```

Make sure you place this file in same folder as your `wp-load.php` file. I just said that because in case you have WordPress installed in a sub-folder.

Whenever you are ready to make your website live, simply remove this file and everything will be back to normal.

**EDIT**

Adding `.maintenance` file in WordPress root will make website go in maintenance mode but it will display default maintenance message.

```
Briefly unavailable for scheduled maintenance. Check back in a minute.
```

If you want to customize this message and want to display some important information for your users, you can create a `maintenance.php` file in `wp-content` folder and add your custom message in it.

You can also add HTML/Image in `maintenance.php` file. Go crazy.

Comment: @birgire sure I will do that. I think that will be great information too!